# Javascript decodeURI makes problems

Tags: javascript, decode

I wish for some help with decoding.

Given parameter: \u00c4   (real key Ä)

The key is packed in a paramter named: reboundContent[2][id] ( \u00c4 )

reboundContent[2][id] is read from the database.

Next I tried following: decodeURI(reboundContent[2][id]) and that doesn't work.

If I create a new string and pass in the parameter everything works perfectly, but I can't give in that parameter.

That's crazy.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Is `\u00c4` passed as a string, within quotes?

Comment: No. That's not possible beacuse of reading in variables form my database via mysql

Comment: _"That's not possible beacuse of reading in variables form my database via mysql"_ What does `console.log(reboundContent[2][id], typeof reboundContent[2][id])` log at `console`?

Comment: The log is: \u00c4 string

Comment: `decodeURI("\u00c4")` returns `"Ä"` here. Is this expected result?

Comment: Yes. I wish for that. But it seems that you have to instantiate a string with the specific key so that it can be formed to certain value like Ä. Therefore I  will need to do a workaround... Found no alternative up to now

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: I don't understand what you ask for...

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Ah, I'm coding with javascript. That's what it stands for. Nothing else. Maybe a bit incorrect header. Sorry for that.

Comment: Maybe the string is literally what you describe, of 6 characters length. Try running it through JSON.parse() or eval() to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @DotBlack, see my answer and check if it solves your problem better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It's more or less good and surely not perfect, but it's a way to solve that.

I was just splitting up the string into it's components. So. I'm looking for the combination \u in the strings I want to check. If that is found I'm deleting all 0 in front to get the right codeword. In this case c4. That can be translated by calling that method.
String.fromCharCode(parseInt('c4', 16));
The original string was copied at methodstart and I'm replacing the \u00c4 with the Ä from the method. That can be done with each element in the string.

Answer (score 1):

From your question and possible solution, it seems that the string containing \u00c4, actually contains the 6 characters "\", "u", "0", "0", "c", and "4".

In order to convert it to the unicode character it is meant to represent, a straightforward approach is to wrap it in quotes and use JSON.parse:

```
var parsedString = JSON.parse('"' + originalString + '"');
```

```js
//Set string to "\u00c4", literally.
//Note that the backslash is escaped
//with a preceding backslash
var string = "\\u00c4";

//check string
console.log(string); // \u00c4

//check string length
console.log(string.length); // has 6 characters

//check first two characters
console.log(string.slice(0,2)); //are "\" and "u"

//convert to actual character
string = JSON.parse('"' + string + '"');

//string is now "Ä"
console.log(string);

//works for longer strings also:
console.log(JSON.parse('"\\u00c4 and \\u00d8"')); // Ä and Ø
```

Using this approach should be far more simple than splitting the string into components, searching for "\u" , deleting the "0"'s and use `String.fromCharCode(parseInt('c4', 16));`

Comment: Hello, Tomas. Thanks for that. I found a fully new way! I'm saving now keycodes for keys. But thanks for that!